# C#, Execute Event Handler in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I'm currently working on a program's subsystem that requires writing data to disk. I've implemented this as a multithreaded Producer-Consumer model that generates packets of data in one thread, puts them in a queue and writes them to disk in another thread.

The program has to use minimal CPU resources, so to avoid the write thread idling while it is waiting for a packet of data to arrive, I extended the ConcurrentQueue class to trigger an Event when a packet has been added to the queue, so that the write function is only active when there is data available. Here's the generate function:

```
        while (writeData)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < packetLength; i++)
            {
                packet.data[i] = genData();
            }

            packet.num++;

            // send packet to queue to be written 
            // this automatically triggers an Event
            queue.Enqueue(packet);
        }
```

My problem is that I haven't been able to figure out how to assign the Event Handler (ie: the write operation) to a seperate thread - as far as I'm aware, Event Handlers in C# are run on the same thread that triggered the event.

I've thought about using the ThreadPool, but I'm unsure as to whether the packets in the queue would be written sequentially or in parallel. Writing packets in parallel would not work in this context, as they are all being written to the same file and have to be written in the order they arrive in. This is what I have so far:

```
   private void writeEventCatch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // catch event and queue a write operation
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(writeToDisk);
    }

    private void writeToDisk(Object stateInfo)
    {
        // this is a struct representing the packet
        nonCompBinData_P packet;

        while (queue.TryDequeue(out packet))
        {
            // write packet to stream
            serialiser.Serialize(fileStream, packet);
            packetsWritten++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without any code?? Please try and improve your question by reading [ask]. - And welcome to SO! :)

Comment: My first Idea would be a plain old Thread that works off of a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) until told to stop. You then only need to share that collection and fill it in one thread, said consumer thread will do the work and the collection handles concurrency.

Comment: Why do you need to multithread this? Is single threaded not fast enough for you?

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the quick answer! Do you know what happens to the thread when the collection blocks?

Comment: @CallumLinington this is a subsystem from a larger program that will need to display and write data from a high throughput source in real time

Comment: @Fildor To clarify, I mean what happens to the consumer thread when there is no data to read?

Comment: [Docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381908(v=vs.110).aspx) sais: "A call to Take **may block until an item is available** to be removed or the token is canceled." - Which is way better than spin/wait. And since you would be using a dedicated Thread - not a problem.

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks! :)

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion - why is blocking a thread better than spinning/waiting?

Comment: @need_help again though - is single threaded not good enough though... If you need things to be in a certain order then at some point you are going to bottleneck. The best choice you have is to make sure that you're not blocking the main application, or write stuff to disk and get eventual consistency. You will bottleneck somewhere - just choose the appropriate place. Guidelines, write to the disk using async/await. Don't block the GUI thread (or main thread). Done.

Comment: Oh yeah, and don't ever use the Thread class. Always use Task/TPL (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is great).

Comment: why shouldn't I use the thread class?

Comment: _" I extended the ConcurrentQueue class to trigger an Event when a packet has been added to the queue"_ -- sounds like you reinvented `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`. _"I haven't been able to figure out how to assign the Event Handler (ie: the write operation) to a seperate thread"_ -- what separate thread? A specific one? Any old thread? Your question is unclear. _"they...have to be written in the order they arrive in"_ -- sounds like you need a single consuming thread; why not just dedicate a thread to `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and write the data from there?

Comment: "why is blocking a thread better than spinning/waiting" - spin/wait needs a lot of CPU: Check condition, Sleep, Wake up, Check Condition , ... Also, if you wait for longer periods to decrease CPU usage, you won't be able to react immediately because the check only will be performed after the Thread is done waiting and rescheduled again. Blocking on the other hand will react (nearly) immediately while not stressing the CPU at all (while blocked).

Answer (score 0):

while (queue.TryDequeue(out packet)) will quit as long as there are no packets to dequeue. what you need to do is start single thread for writing operation deque work items and write data to disk. items will be dequeued one by one and in order they arrive.